# Dart Polymer - passing data through the Contructor with <template repeat>

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, observablelist

I have a ObservableList that will be holding a bunch of Elements. As I add() to the ObservableList I use a `<template repeat>` to show the element.

When I make the element I would like to pass some data (in this case a VO) straight into the Constructor of the new element, then I run the add() on ObservableList. Everything seems to work the way I want until I add(), then I get an error "Exception: No constructor 'MyAlert.' declared in class 'MyAlert'." - where MyAlert is the class name (this constructor definitely exists).

I can print out the VO within the new element, but as soon as it is added to the  I get issues. Can this just not be done and I'll have to pass the data I need via the HTML template?

Thanks,

Robbie

Comment: A code example would be helpful to show what you want to achieve.

Comment: could have to to with a [problem I'm coping currently](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Area%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=14250) but I have not information how you try to to what you want.